# How can send email with flag in python?

Tags: python, smtp, flags

I have a little question. How can in python sending e-mail via smtp with flag, that the recipient opened the message?

Comment: 'yahoo: python smtp dsn list' and on first 10 page I dont't found answer

Comment: Did I said **Google**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_receipt you may choose either RFC-3798-compliant method with `Disposition-Notification-To: <email>` header or non-standard but widely used `Return-Receipt-To: <email>` header.

Technically your question is not about SMTP, because these headers are in the message itself, not in SMTP "envelope headers". As the first step you may form the message with all headers, including delivery status notification, and message body, using a preferred mail program (so called Mail User Agent).